# Unity не загружает сцену

Tags: unity3d

когда делал мультиплеер в юнити столкнулся с такой проблемой: пишет "Game (is loading)". но сцена не загружается:
[image: вот]

за союзника сцена загружается, но за хоста появляется две загрузки которые висят и ничего не делают. ждал их 7 минут и ничего.
вот скрипт, может быть дело в нём:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;

public class JoinCreate : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public InputField field;
    public Text txt;
    public bool CanRandomJoin;
   public void Create()
    {
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
        roomOptions.MaxPlayers = 2;
        
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(field.text, roomOptions);
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(field.text);
        txt.text = "Created, waiting for player";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Joins()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(field.text);   
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        print(PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount);
        PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
        if(PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount != 1)
        {
            if(!CanRandomJoin)
            { 
            PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("Game");
                CanRandomJoin = true;
        }}}
}
```

в консоль ничего не пишет (я поставил режим вывода всех логов в настойках Photon):[image: ничего нет]